# Angularjs Directive Error: ng:areq Bad Argument

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Why am I getting this error **Error: ng:areq Bad Argument** with below directive??

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.home')
        .directive ('centerTabs', {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'app/home/directives/html/center-tabs.template.html',
            controller: centerTabsController,
            controllerAs: 'centerTab',
            scope: {
                accountList: '=',
                emailsOpened: '=',
                contractsOpened: '='
            }
        });

    function centerTabsController() {...
```

And this is withinn HTML Template Below:

```
<center-tabs
            account-list="home.accountList"
            emails-opened="home.emailsOpened"
            contracts-opened="home.contractsOpened"
            layout="row" flex>
</center-tabs>
```

Comment: can you share the html for this directive

Comment: I have edited it with the html.. please see above.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please restructure the directive like so, maybe its a syntax error.

The change is the properties are wrapped in an object and returned inside the directive!

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {

});

app.directive('centerTabs', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    // templateUrl: 'app/home/directives/html/center-tabs.template.html',
    template: '<h1>hello!</h1>',
    controller: function(){},
    controllerAs: 'centerTab',
    scope: {
      accountList: '=',
      emailsOpened: '=',
      contractsOpened: '='
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <center-tabs account-list="home.accountList" emails-opened="home.emailsOpened" contracts-opened="home.contractsOpened" layout="row" flex>
  </center-tabs>
</div>
```